# Null Propagation (Conditional) Operator Syntax Support for Javascript

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anybody know how to handle `Null Propagation (Conditional) Operator` syntax support for Javascript language (al least to turn off warnings)?

[image]

Maybe settings? Or plugins?

Comment: For edge case we can use `javascript.validate.enable: false` setting, but it switches off all JS validation...

Answer (score 0):

Current JavaScript engines to my knowledge do not support this. However, a proposal has been made to introduce this into the language: [Optional Chaining for JavaScript](https://github.com/TC39/proposal-optional-chaining)

For the time being you could use the Babel Plugin mentioned in the proposal: [@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining). The plugin together with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) itself will transpile your code to something that can be used with current engines.

However, I don't know about visual studio support.